# objective-c get all properties of a class (reflection)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Im justing wondering whether there is a way in Xcode obj-c to get all properties of an object (unknown type by code) programatically and than therefore loop through all the properties and obtain the value. I know how to do it in the .net world using reflection, but don't know how to do it in the objective-c.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to read the [*Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=objective-c%20runtime%20programming%20guide&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html&ei=kfocT4WLDcXh0QH7qYWcDg&usg=AFQjCNF-LsrpG8yopUeUTH-x-aicFWT6sA) and [*Objective-C Runtime Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001422-TPXREF101). You'll find functions in the Objective-C runtime such as `class_copyIvarList()`, `class_copyMethodList()`, `object_getInstanceVariable()`, and so on. You can use these to perform all the introspection you like.